# ls -1 is not working as intended in csh

Tags: shell, csh

I want to list all the files in a directory one line after another, for which I am using a sample shell script as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
MY_VAR="$(ls -1)"
echo "$MY_VAR"
```

This works out as expected, however if the same is executed using csh as follows:

```
#!/bin/csh
set MY_VAR = `ls -1`
echo $MY_VAR
```

it outputs all files in one single line, than printing one file per line.

Can any one explain why in csh ls -1 is not working as expected.

Comment: Mandatory reading [Csh programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). Then switch to `bash` or to [zsh](http://zsh.org/)

Comment: Eh? `ls -1` works perfectly. It's the command substitution that isn't behaved. Any other command that emitted multiple lines would have the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From `man csh`, emphasis mine:

> Command substitution
>
> Command substitution is indicated by a command enclosed  in  ``'.   **The
>      output  from  such  a  command is broken into separate words at blanks,
>      tabs and newlines**, and null words are discarded.  The output  is  vari‐
>      able and command substituted and put in place of the original string.
>
> Command  substitutions  **inside  double  quotes  (`"') retain blanks and
>      tabs; only newlines force new words**.  The single final newline does not
>      force  a  new word in any case.  It is thus possible for a command sub‐
>      stitution to yield only part of a word, even if the command  outputs  a
>      complete line.
>
> By  default, the shell since version 6.12 replaces all newline and car‐
>      riage return characters in the command by spaces.  If this is  switched
>      off by unsetting csubstnonl, newlines separate commands as usual.

The entries are assigned in a list; you can access a single entry with e.g. `echo $MY_VAR[2]`.

This is different from the Bourne shell, which doesn't have the concept of a "list" and variables are always strings.

To print all the entries on a single line, use a `foreach` loop:

```
#!/bin/csh
set my_var = "`ls -1`"

foreach e ($my_var)
    echo "$e"
end
```

Adding double quotes around the `` `ls -1` `` is recommended, as this will make sure it works correctly when you have filenames with a space (otherwise such files would show up as two words/list entries).